# How to pass values from Spring Controller to jsp page?( the passed values is to be used to intialise javascript variables in jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp

Below is my Spring Controller code.My intention is to pass the values of variables int a, int b, int c to the Jsp page ADMINRESULTS.

Please note that the values of these variables are to be used to intialise javascript variables in adminhome jsp page

```
@RequestMapping("/adminresults")  //this is called by form action. This does not refer to adminhome jsp page

    public String adminhome(Map<String, Object> model) {




        ArrayList<Block> blockChain = NoobChain.getBlockChain();
        Map<String, Integer> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        if (!blockChain.isEmpty()) {

            if (!NoobChain.isChainValid(blockChain)) {    //if not valid to print the data.
                model.put("tampermsg", "Unathorized acess detected and vote data is attacked.Correct values are ");

                dataMap = NoobChain.validChainData(blockChain);
            } else {
                dataMap = blockChain.get(0).getData();

            }
        }
        String blockchainJsonFromFile = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(blockChain);
        System.out.println("after.." + blockchainJsonFromFile);

        model.put("message", "\n" + dataMap);
        System.out.println("Before extracting DATA is "+dataMap);//to check the format of data map
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        int c=0;
        if (dataMap.containsKey("A"))
        {
            a = dataMap.get("A");
            System.out.println("value for key \"A\" is:- " + a);
        }
        if (dataMap.containsKey("B"))
        {
            b = dataMap.get("B");
            System.out.println("value for key \"B\" is:- " + b);
        }
        if (dataMap.containsKey("C"))
        {
            c = dataMap.get("C");
            System.out.println("value for key \"C\" is:- " + c);
        }
        model.put("a", a);
        model.put("b", b);
        model.put("c", c);



        return "adminhome"; //significance of this code is to return adminhome jsp page
    }
```

Below is a code snippet from adminhome jsp page

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

            var as=8,cs=1,bs=4;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My intention is to intialise the above variables as,bs,cs with int a, int b, int c(from the Spring Controller Mentioned above)

Comment: So much screaming.

Comment: So use `"<%=myVar%>"` ???

Comment: @epascarello.   Sorry for the screaming.

Comment: @epascarello.  Sorry ,can you make the answer more clear??Excuse me.

Comment: did you try with var as="${a}" ?

Comment: Thank you man this works very much.........@Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

> Send json object from controller and assign to your hidden variable on html and use that object in your java script. 
>   Below is code, just a sudo code below
>
> Inside Controller

```
List<Someclass> list = new ArrayList<>();
     Someclass someClass = new Someclass();
     someClass.setKey("a");
     someClass.setValue(1);
     list.add(someClass);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("adminhome");
     modelAndView.addObject("list", gson.toJson(someClass));
```

> JSP

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var someClassJson = $('#"admin"');
      list  admins = JSON.parse(someClassJson.val());
        for (var i = 0; i < admins.lenth; i++) {
       var item = admins[i];
       console.log(someClass.key);
       console.log(someClass.value);
      }
     });
    </script>
    <head>
    <title>Admin Example</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="personScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>
      <Admin/h1> <input type="hidden" id="admin"       value="${list}"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but request. symbol is not resolved (shown error in IntelliJ,shown in red) and sorry I don't get by what "pass HttpServletRequest object in adminHome" means,    Thank You

Comment: Sorry my bad updated code, Please check and let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you Nishant, as am a beginner in java ,I couldnt easily implement your code.The issue was solved with Sanjay's  comment easily, as it was easier for me to implement(as I'm a beginner).   Thanks for the efforts will test your code soon..

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy answer,Thank you Sanjay for helping,Also Nishant Raj(check out his code too,as Im a beginner ,I couldn't implement his code)

In the adminhome jsp page

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

            var aa="${a}",bb="${b}",cc="${c}";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above will fetch the values to javascript variables aa,bb,cc etc from the spring controller.

But please note if the fetched values if need to be used as Integer it must be converted.Presently it is of String type.

The code for it is.

```
 <html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                var aa="${a}",bb="${b}",cc="${c}";
                var as=parseInt(aa),cs=parseInt(cc),bs=parseInt(bb);
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The parseInt will convert it into integer for using it in some future functions if needed.
Thank You all,   Issue solved :)